# question about domain notation

Tags: functions, notation

Is it correct to say "dom f(x) ∈ [0,2]"?
Or can you only say "dom f(x) = [0,2]"?
My teacher said she thinks the first one is incorrect so I just want confirmation.

Comment: In addition, we have that $\text {dom}(f)$ is a set; thus, in general, $\text {dom}(f) \subseteq [0,2]$ and not $\text {dom}(f) \in [0,2]$

Comment: If we consider the function $f$ instead, we have that $f(x) \in [0,2]$ is correct, meaning that the value of $f$ for input $x$ belongs to the interval $[0,2]$. See [Image (and codomain)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics))

Answer (score 4):

You say $\operatorname{dom}(f)=[0,2]$, e.g. The domain is for a function $f$, *not* for $f(x)$, which is a notation for its value at $x$, where $x$ must be a member of the domain. So the second one is also incorrect..